# How can I solve the integral below using complex variables?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How can I solve the integral below using complex variables?

> $$
>   \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\;\mathrm{d}\theta
> $$

---

I know how to solve the integral of $\sin θ$. I replace it by its exponential form and call the exponential $z$. Then integrate over a circle of radius $1$. I end up with an integral of $1/z^2$, which is a pole of multiplicity $2$.

Comment: Hint: $\sin x= \mathop{\rm Im} e^{ix}$...

Comment: I meant using complex analysis, Cauchy integral. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: I haven't tried anything actually. I mean, I know how to solve the integral of $\sin\theta$. I replace it by its exponential form and call the exponential $z$. Then integrate over a circle of radius 1. I end up with an integral of $\frac{1}{z^2}$, which is a pole of multiplicity 2.

Comment: In principle I can do the same thing for my integral. The problem is that I end up with the integral of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}$, and I do not know how to solve that.

Comment: Have you drawn a sketch? What answer do you expect?

Comment: I know the answer if I solve it in the real plane.

Comment: The point is that I want to solve it using complex analysis.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Fabian, $e^{i z} = \cos z + i \sin z$, so $$\int e^{i \theta/2} = \int\limits \cos (\theta/2)dz + i \int\limits \sin (\theta/2)dz$$ so you just need to calculate the imaginary part of the number $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i \theta/2}d \theta$.  This is just a calc one integral.